# How to make a Base64 HmacSHA256 signature of bytes payload in JavaScript equivalent to Java?

Tags: javascript, java, digital-signature, hmac, cryptojs

In Java to make a signature of some data we are using `Mac` instance which allows to sign any byte array. How to make a function in JavaScript which produces the same signature for the same byte array?

An example of Java implementation (method `sign` signs `message` with `HmacSHA256` and than converts `signature` into url-safe base64 string):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    byte[] secret = new byte[5];
    secret[0] = 0x1e;
    secret[1] = 0x03;
    secret[2] = 0x01;
    secret[3] = 0x02;
    secret[4] = 0x03;

    byte[] message = new byte[5];
    message[0] = 0x01;
    message[1] = 0x03;
    message[2] = 0x02;
    message[3] = 0x1e;
    message[4] = 0x03;

    System.out.println(sign(secret, message));
}

private static String sign(byte[] secret, byte[] message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    Mac sha256Hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "HmacSHA256");
    sha256Hmac.init(secretKey);

    byte[] signature = sha256Hmac.doFinal(message);
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(signature);
}
```

The example above produces `q-l6FioFNkAqMIIxX5rs3AF-VnGIzpApCSSDHmnmjF8` signature string. I am trying to create the equivalent of `sign` method in JavaScript to get the same signature.

```
function main(){
    var secret = [5];
    secret[0] = 0x1e;
    secret[1] = 0x03;
    secret[2] = 0x01;
    secret[3] = 0x02;
    secret[4] = 0x03;

    var message = [5];
    message[0] = 0x01;
    message[1] = 0x03;
    message[2] = 0x02;
    message[3] = 0x1e;
    message[4] = 0x03;

    console.log(sign(secret, message));
}

function sign(secret, message){

    // ?

}
```

I couldn't find a way to sign bytes with `CryptoJS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution appeared to be not complicated. Before using `CryptoJS` we have to correctly convert bytes array into a String. After returning `base64` string we should escape it to url friendly string.

```
function sign(secret, message){

    var secretString = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, secret);
    var messageString = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, message);

    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(messageString, secretString);
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 and HmacSHA256 should be included in CryptoJS after install. Try this approach:

```
function sign(secret, message){
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message.join(''), secret.join('')); 
const hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
return hashInBase64}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It returns `nfUj2bwfcLQTTcGxgfNgH2xJiyGt3HORnT2cPraK4ns=` but should return `q-l6FioFNkAqMIIxX5rs3AF-VnGIzpApCSSDHmnmjF8` as described in the question.